# how capture the entire screen in android

Tags: android-layout, screen-capture

In my xml file ,i have a form when i try to capture the screen ,it capture only present visible data but i need to capture entire screens.Please can anybody help me.
I captured the screen by using below code:

View v1 = view.getRootView();

v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();

Comment: i think you cannot catch it by programmatically which are invisible.

Comment: please tell any other ways.

Answer (score 0):

do screen shots in android pro grammatically. this is one way..